# Disable chat event reminders

Tags: support, chat, notifications, email-notification

I keep getting emails reminding me of chat events. I also see these notifications at the inbox in Stack Exchange.

How do I disable these notifications entirely?

Comment: Those in your inbox and email are result of you registering to the events. Remove the registration and you won't get the notifications anymore. Those that only show banner on top of rooms while you're in chat are different story, they **should** go away if you don't visit the room (where the event occurs) for a week, but it might be bugged.

Comment: @ShadowWizard How do I "remove the registration"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find out the chat events you are getting the notifications for (from your [inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox)), visit the **info** pages of corresponding chat rooms and cancel your registrations. Say you had previously registered for the [Happy Hour](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta?tab=schedule) event in [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta). Then click on the **cancel your registration** button from the **schedule** tab.

[image]

Comment: Ah! thanks. Would be nice to have a central location listing all your chat registrations together, instead of having to hunt them one by one.

Comment: @becko chat began as kind of "experiment", or bonus, never as key feature, so naturally it never got any real attention from SE developers. This explains the lack of many expected features, this one being only one of them. But... it works, and pretty well.